# MongoDB / MongoEngine: Get 2 Counts in 1 Query

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I'm trying to minimize the number of database calls in an application.

Is it possible to complete these two queries in a single call?

```
system_0 = System.objects(platform_id=platform_id, type=0).count()
system_1 = System.objects(platform_id=platform_id, type=1).count()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what is mongoengine, but I think you will be capable of translating my mongo shell answer to what is appropriate for you. Yes, you can achieve it with aggregation. For example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ 
   $match : { platform_id : ... }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$type",
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}]);
```

If you have more types than 0, 1, you can exclude them in `$match` as well.